# Handling Firebase 5 Authentication Errors In Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

We have an existing project which has been recently updated to Firebase 5, Swift 4 and our Authentication error handling doesn't appear to be working.

I found several answers here on SO, but those no longer appear to be applicable:

[Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054162/handling-errors-in-new-firebase-and-swift)

[Auth Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732505/how-to-fetch-error-code-from-firebase/50733577#50733577)

Suppose a user is logging in and they enter a valid email and invalid password, which are passed to the following code to authenticate

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: user, password: pw, completion: { (auth, error) in
    if error != nil {
        let errDesc = error?.localizedDescription
        print(errDesc!) //prints 'The password is invalid'
        let err = error!
        let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: err._code)
        switch errCode {
        case .wrongPassword: //Enum case 'wrongPassword' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode?'
            print("wrong password")
        default:
            print("unknown error")
        }
    } else {
        print("succesfully authd")
    }
})
```

Previously, we could use FIRAuthErrorCode to compare to possible errors such as FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidEmail, FIRAuthErrorCodeWrongPassword etc but the code posted above won't compile due to this the error on this line

```
case .wrongPassword:   Enum case 'wrongPassword' not found in type 'AuthErrorCode?'
```

oddly, if I use autofill by typing

```
case AuthErrorCode.wr
```

.wrongPassword is a selectable option and when seleted the compiler shows

```
Enum case 'wrongPassword' is not a member of type 'AuthErrorCode?'
```

even though it was a selectable option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should handle error code by converting Error into NSError.

> ```
>   Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
>     switch error {
>     case .some(let error as NSError) where error.code == AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
>       print("wrong password")
>     case .some(let error):
>       print("Login error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
>     case .none:
>       if let user = authResult?.user {
>         print(user.uid)
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```

Comment: Wow - I didn't see that coming. If I am reading it correctly, what's happening here is it's converting the error to an NSError and getting the integer code of the error, then comparing that to the integer code derived from the rawValue of the possible errors. Great answer! NSError is very un-swifty but the answer works very well. For future readers: *The type [Optional<Wrapped>](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html) is an enumeration with two cases, none and some(Wrapped), which are used to represent values that may or may not be present* Thank you.